# Why same t-score for contrast pairs involve continuous x continuous interaction (emtrends)?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, contrasts

I want to calculate the difference in simple slope estimates for two-way interactions that involve two continuous variables. But I found the t-score is all the same for the contrast-pair results when I treat the second variable as continuous. But when I treat the second variable as categorical, the t-score is different across different contrast pairs.

Could anyone help me understand why the t-score for the contrast results is all the same when I treat the second variable as continuous?

An example is attached below.

````
> rm(list=ls())
> library(reghelper)
> library(emmeans)
> 
> x1 <- sample(40:80,100, replace = T)
> x2 <- sample(c(1,2,3), 100, replace=TRUE)
> 
> x3 <- rnorm(100)
> x4 <- rnorm(100)
> 
> y1 <- x1 + x2 + x1*x2 + x3 + x4 + rnorm(100)
> 
> # Continuous
> fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1*x2 + x3 + x4)
> summary(fit1)

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 * x2 + x3 + x4)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.76124 -0.72406 -0.02281  0.70746  2.22115 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.78452    1.41327   0.555    0.580    
x1           0.97714    0.02297  42.537   <2e-16 ***
x2           0.39638    0.70073   0.566    0.573    
x3           0.92994    0.09283  10.018   <2e-16 ***
x4           0.95184    0.09302  10.233   <2e-16 ***
x1:x2        1.01358    0.01125  90.133   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9653 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9997 
F-statistic: 7.31e+04 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> 
> emtrends(fit1, pairwise ~ x2, var="x1", 
+          at=list(x2=c(1,2,3)))
$emtrends
 x2 x1.trend      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  1     1.99 0.01341 94     1.96     2.02
  2     3.00 0.00922 94     2.99     3.02
  3     4.02 0.01559 94     3.99     4.05

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2       -1.01 0.0112 94 -90.133  <.0001
 1 - 3       -2.03 0.0225 94 -90.133  <.0001
 2 - 3       -1.01 0.0112 94 -90.133  <.0001

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 

> 
> # Categorical
> x2 <- as.factor(x2)
> 
> fit2 <- lm(y1 ~ x1*x2 + x3 + x4)
> summary(fit2)

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 * x2 + x3 + x4)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.93085 -0.75041 -0.04278  0.67447  2.04245 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.85400    0.87455   0.977    0.331    
x1           1.99715    0.01433 139.324   <2e-16 ***
x22          1.68473    1.28046   1.316    0.192    
x23          0.71701    1.41760   0.506    0.614    
x3           0.94231    0.09306  10.126   <2e-16 ***
x4           0.95768    0.09293  10.305   <2e-16 ***
x1:x22       0.98872    0.02133  46.363   <2e-16 ***
x1:x23       2.02893    0.02264  89.602   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9615 on 92 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9998,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9997 
F-statistic: 5.262e+04 on 7 and 92 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> 
> emtrends(fit2, pairwise ~ x2, var="x1", 
+           at=list(x2=c("1","2","3")))
$emtrends
 x2 x1.trend     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1      2.00 0.0143 92     1.97     2.03
 2      2.99 0.0159 92     2.95     3.02
 3      4.03 0.0176 92     3.99     4.06

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2      -0.989 0.0213 92 -46.363  <.0001
 1 - 3      -2.029 0.0226 92 -89.602  <.0001
 2 - 3      -1.040 0.0237 92 -43.920  <.0001

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
> 
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different models! Note the first one has 6 regression coefficients and the second one has 8. When x2 is a factor, it sets up two dummy variables named x22 and x23 which are used in the model in place of just the value of x2 like in the first model. x22 equals 1 when x2=1, and 0 otherwise.  23 equals 1 when x2=3, and 0 otherwise. Look in a regression analysis textbook for details.

I will add that the model `fit1` specifies that the slope of `x1` changes *linearly* with the value of `x2`. Thus, the difference in `x1` slope between `x2=1` and `x2=2` is the same as the difference in `x1` slope between `x2=2` and `x2=3` -- indeed, for any change between `x2=a` and `x2=a+1` for any `a`.